# WCF - Método Post y Ajax/Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, post, wcf

Saludos Amigos,

Vengo por este caminoa pedirles una ayuda ya que estoy mas perdido que camaron en sanduche de queso.

Tengo un Webservice hecho en  WCF

```
**[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
UriTemplate = "GrabaInspeccion")]
void GrabarAlumno(ModeloAlumno Alumno);**


var vFormData = new FormData();
                    vFormData.append("dato1", dato1);
                    vFormData.append("dato2", dato2);
                    vFormData.append("dato3", dato3);
                    vFormData.append("dato4", dato4);
                    vFormData.append("IMAGEN", iamgen);

                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'url',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType:'json',
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        async: true,
                        data: vFormData,
                        success: function (data) 
                        {
                            debugger;
                            var ArregloJson = JSON.stringify(data);
                            console.log(ArregloJson);

                        },
                        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                        {
                            console.log(xhr);
                        }
                    });
```

En el Modelo Alumno tengo
ID
NOMBRE
APELLIDO
CORREO
FOTO (Byte[]) Esto Va a ser grabando como Imagen en SQL y CLOB/BLOB en Oracle

Pero el tema es que no consigo enviar desde jquery/ajax la imagen que capturo desde el filupload menos hacer llegar los demas parametros
Me da errores como 405 / Cors entre otros

Por favor solicito su ayuda Les Agradeceré Millon

Comment: Hola @Vicente. ¡Bienvenido a SOes! ¿Podrías **[edit]** la pregunta y agregar el código mostrando hasta dónde llegaste intentando recibir y enviar la solicitud con jQuery? Imaginate que así sería mucho más sencillo poder ayudarte. Además, ¿podrías mencionar si revisaste o no los permisos en el servidorpara ver si permite hacer un POST?

Comment: Ahi añadi el jquery @Mariano